# Get external API information using serializer data before creating a new object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django

I've added a Profile model linked to User model in Django REST Framework.

Before create a new object through a ModelViewSet I have to create a "customer" in an external API (Python requests) using profile information (not saved yet) and I want to save the returned ID in my Profile model.

Now my ModelViewSet looks like:

**views.py**

```py
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',)
```

When and which is the best way to create the external customer and pass the ID to the serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on perform_create:

```
def perform_create(self,serializer):
    response = requests.post('your request url',data={*customer_save_data*})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        customer_id = response.json()['customer_id']
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user,customer_id=customer_id)
    else:
        #you can raise exception here
```

Comment: The problem is that I need serializer's data into the POST and I cannot access (as read in some other posts) `serializer.data`.

Comment: You can do this in serializer, too.If you share your serializer I'll update my answer